# Access to database tables location created with migrate in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, migrate

I did a homework on Rails using RubyMine.
I need to submit the homework with the database tables . But I can't access database tables file location, because I don't know under the which folder I created with migrate. I have migrated tables at the rubymine terminal
I used postgresql for database.
I will be so happy if you could help me. Thank you from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `schema.rb` file that represents your database under `db/` folder. So this is the answer for your first question.

The answer to second question is in order to deploy your code on a different computer, the third-party softwares need to be installed. In your scenario, this third-party is `postgres` as db server. To deploy your code, just type on your terminal `rake db:setup`. This command will create your database, run migrations and finally seed your database if `db/seed.rb` contains something. As a result, after `rails s` there should be some output.

It is worth to note that `Rails` is db agnostic framework. If you did not use `postgres` specific features then you would use `mysql` or `sqlite` on different computers/servers. But keep in mind that you should change the `adapter` from `config/database.yml` if you want to use another database.

Ödev sunumunda başarılar.

Comment: which 3rd party software can I use? I did not fully understand what the position of the database tables I migrated to the computer.

Comment: If there is `postgres` already installed on the target computer, then `rake db:setup` is enough.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the information I provided. But  I did not fully understand where is the location of migrates in the computer directory.

Comment: The `db/schema.rb` file contains the metadata such as tables, columns and indexes. Your migration files are under `db/migrate` folder. There should be lots of files. You should not think of that because `Rails` knows how to establish database with `rake db:setup` command.

Comment: For example, When I add a table in Microsoft SQL Server Management, it is saved to the c://programfile / microsoft sql server directory. Where is it saved with migrate in Rails?

Comment: Ok the problem is clear now. But I recommend that just build your database using `Rails migration` process. So the answer is `rake db:schema:dump` command. This command dumps your database to `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: Hi again, I did not my problem clearly. I mean how can ı export my database file to send my project to the teacher?

Comment: If you mean Entity Relationship Diagrams then you would use this gem: https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd

Comment: Or you would use PgModeler for postgresql. https://pgmodeler.io/ I hope I help you.